Why is data not encrypted on icloud.developer.apple.com when i am using encrypted field
Here is my sample code of integration with iCloud
let dbName = "GroceryItem1"
let fieldName = "todoTitle1"
@objc func saveItem(name: String) {
        let record = CKRecord(recordType: dbName)
        record.encryptedValues[fieldName] = name
        database.save(record) { record, error in
            if error == nil {
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) {
                    self.fetchItems()
                }
            } else {
                print("Error saving item: \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Unknown error")")
            }
        }
    }

Now my code works fine but what i don't understand is when i login to icloud.developer.apple.com why am i able to see the data, why is it not encrypted?
My database is private as well
If i go to record types i can see the recordfield is encrypted as shown in below screenshot

